# what's the error in adding map on android xamarian?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin-studio

i'm trying to add google map v2 to my Android App in xamarian and sometimes it crashing , it forces to close or it get Null GoogleMap/Crashing when implementing Google Maps Android API v2  and that's my code :

**my XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Support.V4.Graphics;
using Android.Support.V7.AppCompat;

namespace CyclingAndroid
{
    [Activity (Label = "MapActivity")]          
    public class MapActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            var mapFragment = new MapFragment ();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragmentTx.Add (Resource.Id.mainlayout, mapFragment);
            fragmentTx.Commit ();
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Map_View);
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            base.OnResume ();


        }
    }
}
```

and that's my AndroidManiFeast

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="GooglePlayServicesApp.GooglePlayServicesApp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:label="GooglePlayServicesApp">
        <!-- Put your Google Maps V2 API Key here. This key will not work for you.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="yourKey" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

### and it crashing and get that he can't use setcontentview in this class

**and i'm trying to use another way to add map but it get force close to app that using this code**

my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
    p1:layout_height="fill_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout121">
    <TextView
        p1:text="Simple google maps test"
        p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        p1:id="@+id/textView121"
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Support.V4.Graphics;
using Android.Support.V7.AppCompat;

namespace CyclingAndroid
{
    [Activity (Label = "MapActivity")]          
    public class MapActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            var mapFragment = new MapFragment ();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragmentTx.Add (Resource.Id.mainlayout, mapFragment);
            fragmentTx.Commit ();
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Map_View);
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            base.OnResume ();


        }
    }
}
```

and it will be the same Androidmainifeast

my error is ***"Unfortunately, this app has stopped working" after a few seconds***

***and this what i got in logcat***

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable.MapAttrs_liteMode
  at at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00068>
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:896
  at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:4253
  at CyclingAndroid.MapActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00009] in d:\Biker Finder 13-5-2015\BikerFinder 12-5-2015\VR2\Cycling Mobile\CyclingAndroid\Activity\MapActivity.cs:29
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2179
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.8727fe2f-d554-4ad5-a0a8-e6e04355ca49 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable.MapAttrs_liteMode
  at at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
  at at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
  at at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4729)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
  at at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
  at at cyclingandroid.MapActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at at cyclingandroid.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:29)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5117)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
  at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You really should include an error stacktrace to your question.

Comment: i have add the error i have got

Comment: Thats not really an full error trace... just a message. You need a full stacktrace, Google the word. Also Google for logcat ;)

Comment: i have put what appear to me in logcat

Comment: Any help in my issue ?

Comment: 19 views and no answer?

Answer (score 0):

For the first method (declaring the map fragment in xml layout) you do not need to create a new `MapFragment` and add it via `FragmentTransaction`. That is already done via the layout. In order to get the `MapFragment` and instantiate the `GoogleMap` within it, you should do something like the following:

(In OnCreate, after SetContentView)

```
((SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.MapFragmentIdName)).GetMapAsync(this);
```

This assumes that you are using SupportFragments, just change to regular FragmentManager if you are not. Then you should implement `IOnMapReadyCallback` in your activity to be able to manipulate the `GoogleMap` object once it is ready.

Hope that helps!